# Cannot get Stripe Example app to send test payment to Stripe account

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I have tried to use the StripeExample here (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios) to test the ApplePay functionality.  I have set up Stripe and Parse accounts and followed the instructions on the Github page but cannot seem to get the app to communicate with my Stripe dashboard to display the test payments.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mattyohe no errors in Xcode, also nothing in the log on Parse or Stripe.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get it to work, silly newbie mistake.  Was testing through Xcode simulator instead of through iPhone.  Works perfectly when app is run on my iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the stripe example at all?
Did you implement your own test keys in the example?

```
[Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:YOUR_KEY_HERE];
```

Are you specifically only testing apple pay?

From the looks of it you already checked the stripe logs this is the first place I would go to see if there are any logs and if so check for errors. The first step in the process is generating a token, this will show up here. If there are no logs at all then your issue is not with parse, but within the ios app. The generation of a token does not go through parse.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I was able to get the Example app to work.  The problem was just that I was testing through the Xcode simulator; it worked through my iPhone.

Comment: Now I have a new issue in my own app where I am implementing Apple Pay/Stripe.  I get this error: